# select first 200 rows in a sas sql code to pull data from teradata table?

Tags: sql, sas

how do I select first 200 rows in a sas sql code to pull data from teradata table? I tried selelect top / fetch first 200 rows only / rownum < 200.  none of these are working.

Comment: Perhaps you should read up a little on what constitutes a good question on Stack Overflow and then come back and edit/improve your question.  A good question is far more likely to receive a good answer.  I suggest starting here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select top n` if you are using [explicit pass-through](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001384466.htm) (where you send code to be evaluated by the teradata server), but it does not exist in SAS' sql language.

Pass-through example:

```
proc sql;
    /* Create your explicit teradata connection */
    conncect to teradata (user=testuser pass=testpass server=server);

    create table want as
    select * 
    /* Use the results of a teradata query as your data source */
    from connection to teradata (
       /* Your teradata code to be run in the teradata warehouse */
       select top 10 * from TDDB.TDTable
    )
    /* Close the connection */
    disconnect from teradata;
quit;
```

---

Since SAS 9.3 there have been considerably more implicit pass-through possibilities (where SAS creates and submits DBMS specific queries automatically) but I'm not sure if any of these can be used for a limiting command like this. If I had to guess I would say that using the `obs` data step option or `inobs` `proc sql` option might be worth a shot.

> /* I've not tested these methods */
>  libname tdlib teradata user=testuser pass=testpass server=server;
>  data want;
>  set tdlib.TDTable (obs = 10);
>  run;
>  proc sql inobs=10;
>  select * from tdlib.TDTable;
>  quit;

Comment: 13    PROC SQL;
14    connect to teradata(USER=%sysget(USER) PW="&dbpass." MODE=TERADATA TDPID=LLD SERVER=txxxsd) ;
15    CREATE TABLE t.data_wf  AS
16     Select * from connection to teradata (
17     select top 100  distinct b.acct_no
18    ,a.part_id_no
19     ,a.depart_no
20     ,b.criddIid
21      from user1.table1 a  left join  user2.table2 b
22      on  a.col_id = b.col_id
23     );
ERROR: Teradata prepare: Syntax error: expected something between an integer and the 'distinct' keyword. SQL statement was:

Comment: From the TD site: [A SELECT request that specifies the TOP n operator cannot also specify DISTINCT.](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_109A/ch01.3.082.html)